# Identify large (convex) polygons

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I have a point cloud that has several connections. What I want to identify are the largest (by area) irregular (convex) polygons. I put convex in brackets as it is not fully necessary (like in the red polygon case), but polygons with very small corner angles should not be considered. I know that this is quite ambiguous.

Do you have any suggestions? What I tried so far is a kind of brute force approach of growing polygons by adding more and more points and checking for polygon-line intersections. This is of course computationally very demanding for larger point and connection clouds.

[image: Point cloud with connections and large polygons]

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're looking for? Do the polygons have to be faces of the graph? What is your criterion for "nearly convex"? Is the point cloud in two dimensions?

Comment: Maximium area of the polygons. No intersections with any connections. Only 2D. Nearly convex means that the angles at the corners (the outer angles) should not be small (>= min_angle). But for the sake of simplicity only convex polygons would be okay too.

Comment: Seems to me that something like a Delauney triangulation can be used to efficiently compute areas of these polygons.